# How to convert a float array to byte array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I want to convert a float array to a byte array to send it via socket to a python script.
(Im doing this in the Unity engine).

**I tried:**

```
float[] myArray = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

int len = myArray.Length;
byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
int x = 0;

foreach(float f in bytes){
  byte[] t = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
  for(int y = 0; y<4); y++){
    bytes[y + x] = t[y];
    x += 4;
  }
}
```

**The output is this:**

> Assets\PlayerScript.cs(106,27): error CS1002: ; expected
>
> Assets\PlayerScript.cs(106,33): error CS1002: ; expected
>
> Assets\PlayerScript.cs(106,33): error CS1513: } expected

Im not used to work with c# and cant get it to work...
I also looked at some other stackoverflow code but that didnt really help.

Comment: There is an extra `)` after `y<4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
           float[] myArray = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

           int len = myArray.Length;
           List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

           foreach (float f in myArray)
           {
               byte[] t = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
               bytes.AddRange(t);
           }
           byte[] byteArray = bytes.ToArray();
```